# Adjusting column width of datagridview according to content size

Tags: c#, properties, datagridview, autoresize

Guys by specifying the column index,It is possible to set the autoresize property of that column.
Like,

```
 gridview.AutoResizeColumn(1);
```

Is there any way to set this property to the datagridview without having to specify the columns indexes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

> gridview.[AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158593%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to set that value at creation time like :

```
Column myColumn = new Column() { AutoResizeColumn = true };
```

And then add this column to the column list of your gridview

on another hand you can do a "for each" loop to loop all the columns and give them the appropriate param value :

```
for each (Column col in gridview.Columns) {
    col.AutoResizeColumn = true;
}
```

but doing this at initialisation is probably a much stable approach (like having a column template object) and if you need to change value then you call by index this way is suppose :

```
gridview.Columns[index].AutoResizeColumn = false //as you wish
```